# Number generation going Wrong

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to generate a random number and comparing with another number, if they are the same i want the random number to increase by one and then add it to the stage. but if it's different to begin with I want it to directly add it to the stage. but it's not working properly if the numbers are same, it does go through radomize++ but still adds the initial number that was generated messing everything up. can somebnody please help me on how to fix this?

```
 function randomizedorder()
    {
        randomize = Math.floor(Math.random() * (choices.length));

        trace("the random number is" + randomize);

    if (randomize == indexcount ) {
            randomize++;
            trace ("it goes through this pahse" + randomize);

        }
        else {
               addChild(choices [randomize]);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Not sure what's wrong the code here looks okayish.  I think you should consider randomizing/scrambling the list in advance.  Perhaps clone the array then randomize that by picking to swap n spots randomly, then use the cloned array to add children from (and inspect).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`want the random number to increase by one and then add it to the stage`

yet you are increasing it by one and not adding anything to the stage since the addChild is in the else clause.

```
function randomizedorder()
{
    randomize = Math.floor(Math.random() * (choices.length));

    trace("the random number is" + randomize);

    if (randomize == indexcount ) {
        randomize++;
        randomize = randomize % choices.length;
        trace ("it goes through this pahse" + randomize);
    }

    addChild(choices [randomize]);

}
```

Also you need to decide on what to do if randomize is equal to `indexcount` and is also equal to `choices.length-1` in that case you can't use it to undex choices.

Edit: I added the modulus operator so if the randomize goes out of bounds it will go back to 0.

Comment: yes, that works thx. but I also need to know if the random number is out of bounds as in it goes more than the choice length, how do I ask it to, instead of being increased by one decrease by one? well that is a choice is available. because it does happen right now, if I have an index that is at 1 and still I have a choice available at 0, but if the randomize comes to 1, it moves on to 2. I need to ask it to go back to 0. I do know i can ask it to check at the very last else, but then how do i ask it to add it to the stage?

Comment: Edited my answer, you can use the modulus operator to wrap `randomize` back to 0 if its out of bounds.

Comment: oooo fancy.. Thank you so much for teaching me something new :D it solved the problem as well :p I never actually knew about this relation.